# Need assistance setting two buttons of equal width, side by side Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

**Using auto layout I am trying to create two buttons on the bottom like this**

[image]

**After dragging two buttons I set constraints like this**

[image]

**On `Back button` I set `Leading Space to Container Margin` and `Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide`**

**On `Go To Settings button` I set `Trailing Space to Container Margin` and `Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide`**

**Then I `ctrl+Drag` from `Back button` to `Go To Settings button` and set the `Equal Widths` constraint and I get this.**

[image]

**Then I update the `Back button` width same as `Go To Settings button` which is `101` and all constraints turn to blue.**

**But I want both buttons to cover half of the screen no matter what the size of screen is, same as shown in first screen shot, How to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can done it using equal width to 2nd button like this

[image]

and the output is

[image]

Here is [apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW4)

Comment: please can you tell me why you set only 3 constrains on Setting button, you didn't select the left constraint.

Comment: because left constraints of the setting button is right constraint of the back button....so no need to set it...right....

Answer (score 2):

You can have the equal widths constraint between the buttons, but you also have to tell them which is that width you need.

So drag from a button to the superview, add an equal widths constraint. Then in the properties of the constraint you've added, set the `multiplier` to `0.5`, this way your buttons should be on half the screen.

Comment: thanks for replying, your solution also work but Vladimir K solution is bit straight forward, please can you tell me two different approaches but same result which one is efficient?

Comment: @VladimirK's solution is better, chose that one. It probably is the easiest way to solve this.

Comment: :) another solution from Bhavin and also easy, I am confused that there are several ways to solve same issue which is better and efficient? I am asking you because you have higher repo :)

Comment: In my oppinion, the best is to set leading constraint for the first button, trailing for the last button, equal widths for them and set the distance between to 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more constraint - set horizontal space between buttons to 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can followed the layout changes. you will get what you want.

Layout for `Back` button.
[image]
Layout for `Go to Setting` button.

[image]