# How to add constraints to the following two buttons

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have the following View which contains two buttons and a date picker and I am using AutoLayout.

[image]

Both buttons have 0 space for bottom, top, leading and trailing edge. How can I set constraints to the buttons so that they look like in the picture.

I tried setting 0 for leading, trailing, bottom and top and set fixed height, but one buttons has the width bigger than the other one.

I want them to have same width. Any ideas how can fix this ?

Comment: you can control drag from one button to the other and set an equal widths constraint

Comment: check here....its same but at bottom...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620409/need-assistance-setting-two-buttons-auto-layout/29620794#29620794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + Drag from one button to the other and add the Equal Width constraint.

Comment: That should be the only constraint ? Cause AutoLayout is not satisfied :)

Comment: OK, its working, I also set top, trailing and leading edge to 0.