# How to use autolayout with a line of buttons in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, xcode-storyboard

I need to use autolayout so the app will be adapting to all devices, but when i try to use it with a line of buttons it doesnt work :S. Im doing it with the Storyboard.

I want to achieve this:
[image]

Its a trivial app with a picture, question and 4 answers.

But this is what i get with an iPhone 5S:
[image]

I wanted to use stackView, but its only available in iOS 9 or newer and this app have to be used with iOS 8 or newer, so its not an option to use an stackview :S

Hope you could help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: may be this be helpful to you...if you have any query let me know...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620409/need-assistance-setting-two-buttons-auto-layout/29620794#29620794

Comment: @EICaptain that was great, i've done it and works perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: it's required only in portrait orientation or in both portrait and landscape?

Comment: only portrait @abrarulhaq . I'm waiting ios 8 to be deprecated and be able to use stackView so it works like magic

Comment: ok we have to set size classes base constraints for all ui elements i'm posting here in a while with constraints.

Comment: @EICaptain yes srry, thanks for the info, so freaking useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this firstly set size class Regular Height and Compact Width . Then you have to sett constraint for Trailing/Leading/Top/Bottom edges as well as height and width for each element based on requirement. You have to follow Good practice in UI making with use of parent and child view containers to adjust child UI Elements on each screen size.[image: Preview for iPhone 4 inch and iPhone 4.7 inch]. Its big implementation for constraint description. So if you need demo application share your email.Because it's implementation based on your requirement only.