# How to evenly space buttons horizontally in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

How can I evenly space a row of 4 or more buttons horizontally in Xcode? I'm totally new to xcode and I've played around a lot with constraints, but with no success. I would appreciate a step by step explanation if possible, thanks!

Comment: lookup stack views will do what you need i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0llR7sfrkc

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620409/need-assistance-setting-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side-autolayout/29620794#29620794

Comment: The stack views video was helpful

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a container view and apply Leading - Top - Trailing to the superview

2) add a button A and apply leading - top - bottom

3) take button B horizontal space to A - Centre Vertically - Equal width and height

4) take button C horizontal space to B - Centre Vertically - Equal width and height

5) take button D horizontal space to A - Centre Vertically - Equal width and height and TRAILING TO THE SUPER VIEW.

Update Frames.

[image]

Comment: what if I want to keep the widths of the button according to text size?

Comment: How do you add a button to the container view? I only have the option to add items to the parent view for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make a horizontal spacing constraint between each button. Then, change the constraint constant to what you prefer. To add the horizontal spacing constraint, control-drag from one button to the other, and select it from the pop-up menu.