# How do I use autolayout to align these two UIButtons?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a custom UIView XIB file, in which I have placed two buttons:

[Image of Buttons Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik1kG.png)

How can I progammatically (Swift) or using the interface align these buttons to look like this?

Currently, I get this

[Current Buttons (BAD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys7i6.png)

Following Alexander's method, i did this, this is my current constraints and workspace.

[image]

Comment: If you are supporting only iOS9 and above, then add the two buttons to a horizontal `UIStackView` and set it to `Fill Equally`. Then pin the top, leading and trailing edges of the `UIStackView` to the edges of the superview. `UIStackView`s simplify autolayout enormously.

Comment: may be this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620409/need-assistance-setting-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side-autolayout/29620794#29620794

Answer (score 1):

Add following constraint to Button 1:

- Leading space to superview
- Equal Width to Button 2
- Equal Height to Button 2
- Horizontal Spacing to Button 2

For Button 2:

- Trailing Space to SuperView
- Horizontal Spacing to Button 1
- Equal Width to Button 1
- Equal Height to Button 1

Comment: You should pin the buttons to the top and bottom of the superview as well. Right now, neither `y` nor `height` are being constrained (`height` will be assumed from the content of one of the buttons)

Comment: Yes true if height is not constant , otherwise you need to add top and height constraint from superview for vertical position

Answer (score 1):

Just Follow this step :

Step 1.select **LEFT IMAGE** and set these constraint

- Left
- Top
- Bottom

Snapshot show : 
 [image]

Step 2 : Select Right Image and set these constraint :
- Right 
- Top
- Bottom

Snapshot here : 
[image]

Step 3 :Select Left Image and CMD+ Drag mouse from left to right image and select SELECT HORIZONTAL SPACING

Snapshot here : [image]

Step 4 : Select Left Image and CMD+ Drag mouse from left to right image and select EQUAL WIDTH as image shown in step 3.

Solved !

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me, but its not working. Is it because I'm doing it in a UIView XIB file?

Comment: I don't know how to upload images, but these are my constraints, did i maybe miss anything? http://s32.postimg.org/jyxydd0lx/Screen_Shot_2016_04_29_at_6_20_29_PM.png

Comment: select images not view , if u put another uiview on xib then along with view you need to set images constraint too

Comment: what images are you talking about?

Comment: two images(here : button ) on which you are apply constraint

Comment: Could you maybe show me how to do this by code? thanks! (sorry i dont understand what you're saying)

Comment: Why u going through code , through GUI interface u can do it easily .

Comment: because I need to relate the UIView to the UIViewControllers view, and using your constraints (which work normally) isn't working. sorry

Comment: it is working , repeat same step and update final constraint

Answer (score 0):

Add such constraints in IB:
equal widths

equal heights

pin top of one button to top of other

also for bottom

set left, top, width and height for left bottom

Answer (score 0):

1. First "control" click & drag from one button to the other and set it like in IMAGE 1 below.

IMAGE1 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJzDv.jpg

2. Set pins to the opposite corners and unclick "Constraint to Margins"

IMAGE2 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE2zu.jpg