# Resize items with iOS autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm studying the ios autolayout . I understand how to position elements in view anchoring them to a point with coordinates x and y . not well understood though as resize my items depending on the size of the view . how?

[image: my goal]

Answer (score 0):

For item having the size as the parent view, it's really simple:

**1)** Add your item **placing** it inside parent from side to side like this:

[image]

**2)** Add **leading and trailing constraints** like this

[image: idh]

That's it. Build and **run** and **test** on different simulators.

Comment: nks. but for simple objects such as buttons or text field ? @pedrouan

Comment: It's the same. And if you want to maintain some margins, just replace zeros in those text fields for numbers that are representing distances from edges, instead.

Comment: ok , but I make an example . if I give a location to a 5x5 square and define also the distance from the margins . on iphone 6 will be a 5x5 square in that position . on iphone 6 plus will always be a 5x5 square in the same position . right? I wish that the square on iphone 6 plus become largest and smallest of iphone 5 . you understood me?

Comment: Probably yes. But for being sure, just make a sketch, paste here http://pasteboard.co and post the link to it here, so I can see what you mean.

Comment: right now I have a smartphone and then comes easiest to edit my post . I uploaded a picture . practically I mean resize the height and width depending on the device.

Comment: Well you may have posted an image from any tutorial. And my answer is: Yes, the autolayout is the only smart way how to achieve these results. It doesn't matter what UI element it is, if it has frame, it can be placed using constraints. There are many tutorial using this, one of my example, I suggest you to try is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39384795/661022

Comment: the problem is how . I can not figure out how to resize the height and width for each device . in essence , maintain the proportions

Comment: @nunziogiuliocaggegi In autolayout you are not setting widths and heights, you are making constraints - guides, that are only setting relations between edge and item, between item and other item, between item a parent view etc. I got to go know. If my answer helped, please make an appropriate action. Now you can go to try in your project and if some trouble occur, just post another question, and let me know.