# iOS strategy to keep buttons the same size between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

To keep user experience consistent I want to keep UIButtons the same size between different viewcontrollers (though this applies to my text fields as well) Looking for a strategy to do this in a clean way

My initial thought was to set the size relative to the width and height of the screen size (superview), this turned out to be a pain. On different screens sizes the buttons weren't always a good size. It also meant I couldn't put buttons into other views

My current solution is to have a manager class that returns the necessary buttons sizes depending on the screen size, this seems nice since I have total control between the different screen sizes, but it feels a little hacky as it feels like autolayout should have a solution to this

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I take it that you are not planning to use Storyboards?

Comment: @Azzaknight I am using storyboards. How could that help?

Comment: Well if you are using storyboards cant you just go to the size inspector and set them all to be the size that you want them to be?

Comment: @pflous Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39384795/661022, it is briefly explained how to make UIButton sized in different screen sizes

Comment: @Azzaknight a button size that looks nice on a 4'' phone wont look nice on a 5.5'' phone, they'd have to be different between screen sizes but still the same between view controllers, that's the issue

Comment: @pedrouan unfortunately it doesn't help as in that case they just set the height to 44 for all screen sizes. Those buttons are going to look nice on one screen and look tiny or gigantic on another depending on the hard coded value set

Comment: @pflous if you read a bit more attentive, you can notice, that's although it's an example, you can play with constraint according to your will, so exactly like there are spacing constraints, you will make top and bottom spacing constraints to superview and replace that height constraint by them

Comment: Which devices are you targetting?

Comment: @Mr.UB iPhone SE/5, 6 and 6 plus. So i need 4'', 4.7'' and 5.5'' screen sizes

Comment: I think your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think using aspect ratio to superview will solve your case.
[image: xcode screenshot]

Comment: This was my initial approach as mentioned in the question. The issue is then i couldn't put the button in a view as its superview would now be a different size. The other problem is there isn't one ratio that necessarily looks good on all screen sizes