# Add constraints to side by side buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I want to add constraints to these two buttons. I tried almost every variety to set the constraints properly but the constraints are always not set right on other devices, except the device I make the constraints in.

[image: here]

Comment: Make sure you don't have the "Vary Traits" button (which can be seen in the screenshots in the answers) clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need assistance setting two buttons of equal width, side by side Autolayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620409/need-assistance-setting-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side-autolayout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give constraint as in my image

First give constraint to textfield then Select both button and give constraints like in image and be sure that both buttons width and height is same

[image: Constraint]

It should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **step by step guide** for this exact situation:

[image]

**Full length video**: https://vimeo.com/185598058

If you'd like to read it better:

Set up these constraints:

### UITextField:

- top leading constraint
- left leading constraint
- right trailing constraint
- height constraint

### Left UIButton:

- top leading constraint
- left leading constraint
- height constraint

### Right UIButton:

- top leading constraint
- right trailing constraint
- height constraint

### Both UIButtons at the same time:

- spacing constraint (CTRL+drag from left one to the right one)
- equal width constraint 
  [NOTE: Last constraint will ensure the equality of buttons (to each other) on all screen sizes.]

Result:

[image]