# How to set width of different amount of buttons underneath a view in autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I need to figure out how to size a set of `UIButton`s dependent upon an `UIImageVIew` above it. So in some circumstances I'll have 2 buttons that need to be displayed and some circumstances I'll need 3 buttons to be displayed. I'm trying to figure out how display the buttons so they are all the same size and set evenly throughout the width of the image. I know how to do this without AutoLayout but what do I need to do in order to make this work in AutoLayout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148843/ios-autolayout-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side

Comment: It would help if you were to post mock-ups as in the link above for what you are trying to do.  Prose is not the best medium for a visual problem.

Comment: Are the count of button will change in same view i.e. are you going to show hide one button or these are different views altogather?

Comment: What i want to do is not display the button at all and then have the three buttons now span the entire width of the imageview with padding to both side of the button. I wish i could show you guys some sort of mockup but i cant show the one from my company. Does anyone know where i can make one up myself?

Comment: OK well i figured out what to do. It is possible to actually add another view as the parameter for a metric in the visual format string. So in order to tell autolayout to span all four buttons evenly across the length of the image view all i had to do was this

Comment: `[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_english_button]-5-[_spanish_button(_english_button)]-5-[_chinese_button(_english_button)]-5-[_french_button(_english_button)]-0-|"
                                                                options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_english_button,_spanish_button,_chinese_button,_french_button)]]`

Comment: SO what i did was for the horizonatal constranit was place the spacing of the buttons in the format string then set the width of each button to eachothers width like so ```H:|-0-[view1(view2)]-5-[view2]-0-|``` This would span 2 buttons along the set width of its superview with even width and a spacing of 5 between them.

Answer (score 0):

`[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_english_button]-5-[_spanish_button(_englis‌​h_button)]-5-[_chinese_button(_english_button)]-5-[_french_button(_english_button‌​)]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_english_button,_spanish_button,_chinese_bu‌​tton,_french_button)]]` Read my comments on the question to see what its doing