# Autolayout: Imageview and labels

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift2

I am trying to achieve a header look similar to Instagram with an imageView on the far left and 3 UILabels for the posts, followers, and following. I am having trouble achieving this in autolayout, specifically the horizontal spacing so that it is equally space across all devices. When I do auto layout, the labels are not evenly spaced and get truncated. Any ideas as to how I can solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: if you don't mind supporting only iOS 9, you can do this using stackviews...

Comment: @Commander147 I'm looking for answers specific to my question as this problem may arise again. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: basically you want to specify width equality for your three labels, here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28149068/4761517

Comment: @Commander147 That link helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

[image]

---

and here is the raw `xib` file with the constraints, if you'd like to take a deeper look how I have built it up:

#### View.xib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9531" systemVersion="15C50" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="9529"/>
        <capability name="Aspect ratio constraints" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="93"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="dx4-Jc-VhS">
                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="77" height="77"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="dx4-Jc-VhS" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="7hG-uk-QY2"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumScaleFactor="0.5" adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="DIH-73-jei">
                    <rect key="frame" x="252" y="8" width="60" height="24"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="24" id="M4e-ka-Nbw"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumScaleFactor="0.5" adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="i7h-Ht-kAi">
                    <rect key="frame" x="184" y="8" width="60" height="24"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumScaleFactor="0.5" adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yDX-xV-j2U">
                    <rect key="frame" x="116" y="8" width="60" height="24"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="60" id="dLL-w6-I5C"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumScaleFactor="0.5" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZYY-b1-nBH">
                    <rect key="frame" x="116.5" y="36" width="60" height="21"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumScaleFactor="0.5" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7ao-CO-oe0">
                    <rect key="frame" x="184" y="36" width="60" height="21"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumScaleFactor="0.5" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="t6Q-M4-Jz0">
                    <rect key="frame" x="252" y="36" width="60" height="21"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="JzX-Tc-RP8"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="i7h-Ht-kAi" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="centerY" id="4kA-0u-t4A"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="dx4-Jc-VhS" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="Bgt-e6-X9u"/>
                <constraint firstItem="7ao-CO-oe0" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="i7h-Ht-kAi" secondAttribute="width" id="CPx-Jk-7q3"/>
                <constraint firstItem="7ao-CO-oe0" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="ZYY-b1-nBH" secondAttribute="centerY" id="F3q-A8-pXS"/>
                <constraint firstItem="DIH-73-jei" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="i7h-Ht-kAi" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="HlC-6s-TUN"/>
                <constraint firstItem="DIH-73-jei" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="width" id="PxV-sd-GCV"/>
                <constraint firstItem="DIH-73-jei" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="height" id="Stq-AB-hyP"/>
                <constraint firstItem="7ao-CO-oe0" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="ZYY-b1-nBH" secondAttribute="height" id="Tw1-1F-66D"/>
                <constraint firstItem="i7h-Ht-kAi" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="WKz-Ds-5RX"/>
                <constraint firstItem="dx4-Jc-VhS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="ase-Fc-VNG"/>
                <constraint firstItem="t6Q-M4-Jz0" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="DIH-73-jei" secondAttribute="width" id="cag-85-mNS"/>
                <constraint firstItem="i7h-Ht-kAi" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="width" id="czV-kf-29P"/>
                <constraint firstItem="i7h-Ht-kAi" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="height" id="doF-G5-ewa"/>
                <constraint firstItem="t6Q-M4-Jz0" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="ZYY-b1-nBH" secondAttribute="height" id="fSw-H8-yMk"/>
                <constraint firstItem="t6Q-M4-Jz0" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="ZYY-b1-nBH" secondAttribute="centerY" id="gye-vS-aNp"/>
                <constraint firstItem="t6Q-M4-Jz0" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="DIH-73-jei" secondAttribute="centerX" id="kEo-1I-ZFN"/>
                <constraint firstItem="dx4-Jc-VhS" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="centerY" id="llB-Hy-05T"/>
                <constraint firstItem="7ao-CO-oe0" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="i7h-Ht-kAi" secondAttribute="centerX" id="oBf-jc-iLR"/>
                <constraint firstItem="ZYY-b1-nBH" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="width" id="obW-uC-rIr"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="DIH-73-jei" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="qEY-V0-NM6"/>
                <constraint firstItem="ZYY-b1-nBH" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="centerX" id="qZ0-QE-Z49"/>
                <constraint firstItem="yDX-xV-j2U" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="dx4-Jc-VhS" secondAttribute="top" id="t13-zB-C5B"/>
                <constraint firstItem="t6Q-M4-Jz0" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="DIH-73-jei" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="4" id="udZ-0h-vdz"/>
                <constraint firstItem="dx4-Jc-VhS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="vFh-rW-JtQ"/>
                <constraint firstItem="DIH-73-jei" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="yDX-xV-j2U" secondAttribute="centerY" id="x2Z-nL-xJF"/>
                <constraint firstItem="yDX-xV-j2U" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="dx4-Jc-VhS" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="zSX-Vg-3Wi"/>
            </constraints>
            <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="351" y="180.5"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```