# UICollectionViewCell sizeForRowAtIndexPath and Two Views side by side

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to accomplish what the Imgur app has done in one of their UICollectionViewCells in their about view. See below:

[image]

I want 1 UICollectionViewCell but instead of 3 sections of views inside the cell, I just want two (comments and posts).

For my UICollectionView I am resizing the cell at runtime to make it fit almost the whole screen minus a bit for margin's sake because I want to make a card view like Imgur.

I followed this stackoverflow post to get 2 views side by side: [iOS Autolayout: two buttons of equal width, side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148843/ios-autolayout-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side)

and I am able to get 2 views side by side of equal width. Here's what they look like in the storyboard:

[image]
 but when I run the app, my views get stretched because of the autoresizing. See below:

[image]

How can I get the views to both be of equal width and have equal spacing between, before and after the views?

Comment: There have equal spacing and equal width and height too. So what else you want?

Comment: Yes they do have equal spacing, width and height, but the width is the incorrect width. Notice the difference between my top and bottom images. The top one has square grey views and the bottom one has rectangle grey views, indicating that the views are being stretched. I don't want that.

Comment: Yeah You are right. So did you try `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ` as a solution.? Its better if you can show me your storyboard image of this layout.

Comment: Yes I am using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and resizing the UICollectionViewCell at runtime using the delegate method collectionView: sizeForItemAt method.

Comment: Your approach is absolutely right. So to find out the issue point add storyboard image and code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **UIStackView**. It provides an easy way to lay out a series of views horizontally or vertically.

Select the two views and click on the new Stack button in the Auto Layout toolbar at the bottom right of the storyboard canvas:

[image]

Give constraints to your stack view from top, left, right and bottom. Then make your **Attributes Inspector** of the stack view like this:

[image]

NB. If you want to learn more about Stack View, follow this fantastic tutorial in Ray Wenderlich: https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Believe me most of the complexities associated with Autolayout will become trivial once you learned Stack View

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I can already tell this is really going to help!