# Area of the selected UIButton iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, size, selected

I have a set of UIButtons with identical diameters but diffrent length titles embedded in the view.

When I select the buttons the selection area covers only the title meaning that they look like they have different sizes, see image below.
[image]

How do I set in Swift the same size of the selected area?

EDIT:

The buttons are of the same width (see image below) and are distributed using autolayout.
[image]

Moreover when I set the background of the buttons to some color it does fill the whole button; see below
[image]

So only the `is Selected` attribute is causing the problem.

Comment: You could set the frame (== hit area) of the button. But you should create background image yourself, or add UILabel on this button (do not forget set label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true)

Comment: Are these button laid out in a horizontal layout ? By default, UIButton adjusts its size just enough to fit the text. You can try setting buttons' layout constraints in such a way that all buttons have equal widths and are aligned horizontally along same axis.

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: no I have not got

Answer (score -1):

You can embed these buttons in a Horizontal UIStackView, and set the Distribution to fill Equally.

Comment: As above, It is not really the answer to the question

Answer (score -1):

if you want same size of selection area then you can use Autolayout..

refer link
[same size of the selected area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148843/ios-autolayout-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side)

Comment: Itis not really the answer to the question